# How to detect if Java is enabled in IE?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine whether client browser has java installed and can launch applets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177070/determine-whether-client-browser-has-java-installed-and-can-launch-applets)

I would like to run a check to see whether Java is not installed or if it's disabled / blocked in IE.

I have tried [navigator.javaEnabled()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_nav_javaenabled.asp) and this works as expected in Firefox (v10.0.2), but in IE8 it returns TRUE.  However, IE displays a prompt to the user:

> The page you are viewing uses Java.
>   More information on Java support
>   is available from the Microsoft website.

The issue I have with this is, there is a checkbox `"Do not show this message again"` that can obviously be ticked and then there would no longer be any prompt to the user that Java is not enabled.

How can I handle lack of Java support in IE?

Comment: Closed, but check out this link which might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From [this](http://www.builtfromsource.com/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/#comment-426) link:
>
> > navigator.javaEnabled() does not reveal whether Java is installed or
> >     not in IE. It merely tells you if the applet tag is enabled or
> >     disabled.
> >
> > You can disable the applet tag in the IE security settings … Tools ->
> >     Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Java Permissions ->
> >     Disable Java
> >
> > This will cause javaEnabled() to be false, yet Java is still
> >     installed. For that matter, it isn’t disabled either. Only the applet
> >     tag is disabled.

And from the [same](http://www.builtfromsource.com/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/) link:

> The JRE (formerly Java Virtual Machine, or JVM) is actually more
>   difficult to handle than you would think. Determining if Java is
>   installed is easy—a quick call to navigator.javaEnabled() returns a
>   simple Boolean.* The problem is detecting the version and provider
>   (Microsoft or Sun).
>
> I never found a satisfactory solution to this. The gist is this: to
>   get this information, you must load a Java applet.

Here's another example:

[Determine whether client browser has java installed and can launch applets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177070/determine-whether-client-browser-has-java-installed-and-can-launch-applets)