# How to check if java is enabled on Internet Explorer

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer

I have tried navigator.javaEnabled() and this works as expected in Firefox but in IE11 returns TRUE.How can i detect if Java is enabled on IE9,10,11??

Comment: Already awnsered here:
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569795/how-to-detect-if-java-is-enabled-in-ie)

Comment: the links dont work..

Comment: @epascarello he has already used the solution proposed in the answer but it's not working on Ie9 and above according to him.

Comment: A second-level duplicate also proposes an approach using `isRunning()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177332/209103

Comment: Someone close this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177070/determine-whether-client-browser-has-java-installed-and-can-launch-applets/1177332#1177332 which is the dupe I meant to close it with, copied the wrong url.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using jars?